# dividing time using Java

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime, java-time

I am doing yahoo product API for getting the products from yahoo using time limit. I pass Start time and end time to get the products available between that date. Passing those dates with the url they provide for getting the products.

In yahoo there is limitation to get only 1000 products per call so what i am doing is give 1 month time limit and make a call and get the products in that time limit. some cases it wont exceed 1000 but in some case if it will exceed 1000 products i want to divide the time into half (1 month to 15 day time gap) and check again and repeat this until i get less than 1000 products in that time stamp.

I have done all other things except dividing time. please help me with that.

Comment: Don't know about joda time. But you can use java.util.Calendar to achieve this. You have start time, and end time as 2 calendar objects. Recursively divide the interval to shorter intervals, by moving the end calendar to the mid point. `endCalendar.setTime(endCalender.getTimeinMillis - (endCalender.getTimeInMillis - startCalender.getTimeInMillis)/2)`

Comment: i am giving time as hard coded now. not taking the system time stamp. for example 
private static final Long start_date=20140424101010L;
 private static final Long end_date=20140430101010L;
consider this is the time i have given. yyyymmddhhmmss and with in this time limit i am checking and if it is exceeding i need to divide that time. if i am checking date 01 of 05 th month to date 30 of 05 month and if it exceed 1000 i want to check that from 15 th of 05 th month to 30th like that.

Comment: You can construct Calendar objects from the timestamps you have given. A calendar object no necessarily takes system time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library:

```
Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start,end);
int halfDiff = diff.getSeconds()/2;
end = end.minusSeconds(halfDiff)
```

Comment: static List<Interval> splitDuration(DateTime start, DateTime end, long chunkAmount, long chunkSize)
 {
        long millis = start.getMillis();
        List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<Interval>();

        for(int i = 0; i < chunkAmount; ++i) {
            list.add(new Interval(millis, millis += chunkSize));
        }

        list.add(new Interval(millis, end.getMillis()));
        return list;
    }
this is the sample i am got but as i am new to joda time i am confused with this

Comment: Please read joda javadocs to understand the code I provided. I answered only the part about dividing the time.

Comment: @sarath Search StackOverflow.com for "joda". You will find many examples to help you quickly get the hang of Joda-Time. Well worth the effort. The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome; avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

`java.time.Duration` is a dividable time interval

```
LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime t2 = t1.plusMonths(1);
Duration t = Duration.between(t1, t2).dividedBy(2);
t2 = t1.plus(t);
```